# Environment variables and @Value can't work together on Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, docker, spring-boot, docker-compose

I have a Spring boot app that connects to a Redis instance that works as a cache. When I'm in dev environment, I have the following:

```
---

spring:
  profiles: default
redis: 
  host: localhost
  port: 6379
```

And my cache configuration class is like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class CacheConfiguration {

   @Value("${redis.host}") 
   String redisHost;

   @Value("${redis.port}") 
   int redisPort;
```

In production, this app is Dockerized, and I have the following `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
redis: 
  image: tutum/redis
  ports:
    - "6379:6379"
  volumes:
    - /data
app: 
  build: .
  ports:
    - "8080:8080"
  links:
    - redis
```

And the `application.yml` is:

```
---

spring:
  profiles: docker
redis: 
  host: redis
  port: 6379
```

To start the app on Docker, I run with `-Dspring.profiles.active=docker`, but when the app is starting up, the following error happens:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private int com.inkdrop.config.cache.CacheConfiguration.redisPort; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [int]; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "tcp://172.17.0.3:6379"
```

For some reason, Spring Boot is reading the `redis.port` as `tcp://172.17.0.3:6379`. So for tests proposes, I removed the `@Value` annotations from  `CacheConfiguration` class, and set it manually to `redis` as host and `6379` as port and it worked. Seems like when using environment variables and `@Value`, Spring get lost. Anyone have an idea?

Comment: Which Spring Boot version are you using? Also I would try setting the environment variable in the docker compose file itself: `environment: redis.port=6379`, just to see what happens.

Comment: Using 1.3.4 now. I'll try it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on the [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/link-env-deprecated/):

> Compose uses Docker links to expose services containers to one
>   another. Each linked container injects a set of environment variables,
>   **each of which begins with the uppercase name of the container**.

Docker Compose would create an Environment Variable representing the *Full URL* of the container using ***name_PORT*** format, e.g. `REDIS_PORT=tcp://172.17.0.5:6379`.

And based on your `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
redis: 
  image: tutum/redis
  ports:
    - "6379:6379"
  volumes:
    - /data
```

You would have an Environment Variable named `REDIS_PORT` with a value equals to `tcp://172.17.0.3:6379`.Since OS environment variables have more precedence with respect to Profile-specific application properties, Spring Boot would pick up the `REDIS_PORT` value over `redis.port`, hence the error:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Could not autowire field: private int
>   com.inkdrop.config.cache.CacheConfiguration.redisPort; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed
>   to convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [int];
>   nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string:
>   "tcp://172.17.0.3:6379"

As a workaround for this problem, you either should override the `REDIS_PORT` environment variable with your port value or rename your config name from `redis.name` to anything less controversial.

Kinda off topic but just quoting from `tutum-docker-redis` [Github repository](https://github.com/tutumcloud/redis):

> This image will be deprecated soon. Please use the docker official
>   image: https://hub.docker.com/_/redis/

Comment: I'm not at the dev computer right now, I'll try it later. for now, I think thats exactly what happened. I'll accept this answer now :D