# ConverterNotFoundException: -Dserver.port=80-noverify No converter found ... String to Integer

Tags: spring-boot

I'm starting my Spring Boot application from Eclipse with this VM parameter

```
-Dserver.port=80
```

[image]

**application.yml**

```
server:
  port: 8080
```

but I get the following exception *"No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Integer]"*.

```
Running with Spring Boot v1.5.4.RELEASE, Spring v4.3.9.RELEASE
...

2017-07-19 11:26:55.299 ERROR 5968 --- [           main] o.s.b.b.PropertiesConfigurationFactory   : Properties configuration failed validation
2017-07-19 11:26:55.299 ERROR 5968 --- [           main] o.s.b.b.PropertiesConfigurationFactory   : Field error in object 'server' on field 'port': rejected value [80-noverify]; codes [typeMismatch.server.port,typeMismatch.port,typeMismatch.java.lang.Integer,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [server.port,port]; arguments []; default message [port]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Integer' for property 'port'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Integer]]
Field error in object 'server' on field 'port': rejected value [80-noverify]; codes [typeMismatch.server.port,typeMismatch.port,typeMismatch.java.lang.Integer,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [server.port,port]; arguments []; default message [port]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Integer' for property 'port'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Integer]]

...

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Binding to target org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerProperties@caaddaea failed:

    Property: server.port
    Value: 80-noverify
    Reason: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Integer' for property 'port'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Integer]


Action:

Update your application's configuration
```

If I use the property `server.port` in my `application.yml` it works, no problem.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for any help.

Comment: can we have look at your `application.yml` i suspect your port string is the issue here

Comment: can you also show the `pom.xml`? Looks like you're just missing a converter, are you excluding any dependencies that come with Spring Boot?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37102273/environment-variables-and-value-cant-work-together-on-spring-boot

Comment: @Ulug Toprak I added the application.yml / @cahen I am excluding something, but that is only `spring-boot-starter-logging` @Tanmay Delhikar thanks, that looks similar but a little different, I must read this slowly to understand. Only I don't use docker.

Comment: What I think is strange, is the value `80-noverify` that get's injected instead of just `80`. Obviously `80-noverify` is a bad Integer...

Comment: you could try OS environment variable mode `$ SERVER_PORT=80 java -jar <path/to/my/jar>`

Comment: I would like to start this application from eclipse, because of debugging in eclipse.

Comment: `-noverify` is a valid JVM option. You have probably set it somewhere and a space between parameters gets lost somehow. I don't use Eclipse so I can't check - can't you use the Valriables button to set a `-D`?

Comment: Ok, I found some posts with `-noverify` in relation to `javaagent`, but I don't know how it gets in the value!? The _Variables_ button is eclipse specific stuff, unrelated. If I add `-Dserver.port='80'` the value will be `'80'-noverify`. I think you are right, there is a problem with spacing somewhere, only I never set `-noverify` anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is caused by the spring boot run configuration: In the run configuration, just disable "Fast startup" and the problem will go away. This option causes -noverify to be added as a VM argument, but, unfortunately, with no spaces.